# Css: adjust height of one element according to parent, keep height of other elements

Tags: css, height

What i am trying to achieve is, that div 1 and 3 should keep their height, while div 2 should adjust to the height of the container.

[image]

A solution, which works on all the major mobile browsers would be great.

Comment: Use % to set height of the divs , like 25% - div1 , 25% - div3 , 50% - div2. It should work with any viewport

Comment: @YounisArM you're missing a **key** piece of information. Percentage heights require the parent element to have a height set. If that height is a percentage also, you must continue up the tree until you hit `html` and it inherits from the viewport or a non percentage value is used.

Comment: @YounisArM 1 and 3 should keep their height static, just 2 should change.
The container has height: 100vh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flexbox` is a great option for this and all you have to do is set `flex-grow: 1` to the element that needs to be dynamic an fill the remaining space.

#### Fixed Height Example

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
}

header,
footer {
  min-height: 75px;
}

header {
  background-color: gold;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

footer {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header>1</header>
  <main>2</main>
  <footer>3</footer>
</section>
```

#### Viewport Example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header,
footer {
  min-height: 75px;
}

header {
  background-color: gold;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

footer {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<header>1</header>
<main>2</main>
<footer>3</footer>
```

Comment: You should be pretty solid, [**flexbox caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). A lot of frameworks are switching to or already have an option to use flexbox.